# Kernel Panic installing from USB stick and PXE (very old Fujitsu Lifebook B2154)

Tags: kernel, system-installation, fujitsu-siemens

I'm trying to resuscitate an old fujitsu b2154 with touch screen.
It only can boot using floppy disk or pxe. 
Does not recognize external cdrom/dvd and will never boot using usb stick.

I tried too many flavours and forks of ubuntu (ubuntu, kubuntu, lubuntu, xubuntu, puppy, mint, and others) and too many versions from 8.04 to 14.04.

i create the usb installer with lili, unetbootin o others and a floppy with plop boot manager. When i try to boot live or install, i get a kernel panic.

i tried to boot using pxe, and boots fine, it also starts installing, but suddenly i get a message saying that some .deb files were not found. In fact, the .deb files are in the usb drive and the /tftboot/imagecdrom... 
when i try to boot live cd's I get a kernel panic.

Curiously, i can boot ALL the puppy versions to the GUI, but when i install, it does not install all the files with the full installation.

WHAT I AM DOING WRONG?

Answer (score 0):

Fujitsu LIFEBOOK B2154 is a very old laptop (14 years?) and the CPU does not appear to support PAE so you will not be able to use a recent Ubuntu version on it. The Trident GPU is unlikely to still be supported. Your best hope is to install an old version of Debian ([install report #1](http://users.tkk.fi/jjvayryn/B2154.html), [install report #2](http://www.minus1.de/s/lifebook-linux.html)). Even then it could be a lot of work. You might also consider selling it and buying a more capable laptop (you can get a second hand Thinkpad T42 for less than US$50 now).